# Elasticsearch not running when I try to edit the elasticsearch.yml file

Tags: elasticsearch

elasticsearch.bat file opens and closes instantly when I try to add something to the elasticsearch.yml file. -- **Version 7.4**

I've tried adding the following lines in elasticsearch.yml file:

```
action.auto_create_index=false
index.mapper_dynamic=false
```

It works fine when everything is commented with '#' though. This is the configuration file for elasticsearch:--

```
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
#cluster.name: my-application
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
#node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
#path.data: /path/to/data
#
# Path to log files:
#
#path.logs: /path/to/logs
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
#network.host: 192.168.0.1
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
#http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
#cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]
#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
#gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the gateway module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: true
```

and I'm trying to enter my lines at the last here (without the #)

action.auto_create_index=false

index.mapper_dynamic=false

Comment: Witch version? Plz share the config file (hiding ip if needed)

Answer (score 0):

I got the exception like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the [action.auto_create_index] setting value [false] is too restrictive. disable [action.auto_create_index] or set it to [.watches,.triggered_watches,.watcher-history-*]
```

it means that some Watcher need to create index when ES start, so you can set it in config file.

```
action.auto_create_index: ".watches,.triggered_watches,.watcher-history-*"
```

About `index.mapper_dynamic`, it's a index level config, now ES only allow set it by using `PUT index/_settings`